# Count NaN in Python list

Tags: python

How to I count the occurrences of `NaN` in my list? My data looks like this:

```
[365788, 267102, 170941, 'NaN', 243293, 267093, 'NaN', 370448, 'NaN', 197091]
```

Comment: Are those really `'NaN'` strings in your list, rather than actual floating-point NaNs? (If so, then why?) If they're real floating-point NaNs, ordinary "count this thing" answers will be foiled by `NaN != NaN`.

Comment: It turns out they are 'NaN' strings and the list.count('NaN') method works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(yourlist)
```

You will have the number of occurences for every unique value of your list

Another option is:

Use the `count` method of a list:

`yourlist.count('Nan')`

Comment: Except that, if those values are actual NaNs (i.e. `float('NaN')`), none of these methods work.

Comment: Actually... that's right. I hope the answers have a solution that works, otherwise I will try to update mine when I get off work.

Comment: If it's a 'real' NaN: `import math; len([0 for x in your_list if math.isnan(x)])`

Comment: @Ryan I would use `sum(math.isnan(x) for x in your_list)` more memory efficient :)

Comment: This is better! I was considering using sum and forgot that it takes a generator, so I didn't want to iterate twice. Len I believe is constant?

Comment: As I've just found out, `math.isnan(x)` doesn't like it if `x` isn't a float type, e.g. None. `x if x is not None else 0` helps in this situation.